# NginX as HTTPS reverse proxy for multiple sub-domains?

Tags: linux, nginx, https, docker, reverse-proxy

I have one IP address on my Linux box, and would like to serve HTTPS websites in this form:

```
https://landing.example.com

https://site-01.example.com/index.html
https://site-01.example.com/files/index.html
https://site-01.example.com/store/index.html

https://site-02.example.com/index.html
https://site-02.example.com/files/index.html
https://site-02.example.com/store/index.html
```

Each of these websites is a Docker container on the same host, so my idea were setting up an NginX reverse proxy Docker container.

There are many howto's about NginX as reverse proxy, but what I want to do is different from the text book example, as I have HTTPS, multiple sub-domains and multiple URL's.

**Questions**

Does anyone know of howto's that deal with this type of setup, or perhaps can tell me what the technical key words I should search for are?

At this point I don't know where to start, so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add A-records to you DNS manager that will redirect all your subdomains to the IP address of the host machine.
Then in your NGINX config you can do something like this.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name landing.example.com;
    location /static {
            alias /home/example-dir/staticfiles;
    }
    access_log  /home/example-dir/nginx-access.log;
    error_log  /home/example-dir/nginx-error.log info;
  }
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site-01.example.com;
    location /static {
            alias /home/example-dir2/staticfiles;
    }
}
```